# Bootstrap make collapsible submenus

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create the same menu as it is shown [Here](http://getbootstrap.ru/docs/v4-alpha/components/collapse/)

So I got 2 panels and I when some panel is clicked, I need to collapse currently open panel and show the clicked one (as it is showed in the example). Only 1 panel should be open at a time. I tried to do that with the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.collapse', function(){
    $('.collapse').removeClass('in');

});
```

but it is hiding all open panels immediately and without smooth animation. Any ideas how to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: please show more code. [Check this](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/xPBaPM)

Comment: the pen does not work, shows errors in the console

Comment: Check the same link again, I was working on something on the same Pen, hence the confusion :)